# How to remove the horizontal slim bar for bottombar in Android

Tags: android, navigationbar

I am using the bottombar from GitHub. I cannot see the bar in its demo chart, but I got a slim horizontal bar like below, how to hide/eliminate it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it can be hide from ver2.0.2 using app:bb_showShadow="**false**", the default is true.

```
<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
app:bb_showShadow="false" />
```